# Will Code Migrations update my database, always? If so, how to I access a schema other than dbo?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC 5 app. I created a class in my Models folder for a table and then created a controller using the class as a model. What I didn't think of when I did this, was the fact that the table I'm modeling is in a database schema other than dbo. I was only after getting my website up to the point where I could go to the Index method and finding that it didn't render any data from the table, that I realized my mistake. So I went into the class I created in Models and added the following attribute to the table:

```
[Table("Interview", Schema = "Prism")]
```

Next I compiled it and VS was happy as a clam. So I ran it, navigated to the controller's Index and then everything went belly up. VS gave me this error message:

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=The model backing the 'PrismDeleteInterviewDB' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).
  Source=EntityFramework
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.<CreateInitializationAction>b__e()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<InitializeDatabase>b__4(InternalContext c)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator()
       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator()
       at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       at PrismDeleteInterview.Controllers.InterviewsController.Index() in D:\Websites\PrismDeleteInterview\PrismDeleteInterview\Controllers\InterviewsController.cs:line 20
       at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
       at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
  InnerException:
```

My overriding concern is that the last thing I want EF to do is wipe out the database. The phrase, "Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database..." is what concerns me. Updating a database to me means it's changing the database in some way, possibly dropping tables, etc. This database isn't just a temporary thing that I'm working on, alone from the rest of my co-workers. It exists and has real data in it. So, will this wipe out my database or not?

Comment: Migrations are not intended to wipe out the existing database, but it does depend on the change as to whether it will drop the table. If you examine the Up() method it will show you the changes before you apply them. Also make sure automatic migrations are off.

Comment: First, thank you Steve for your comments. At the moment I can't find the Up() method you refer to, but that's most likely due to ignorance on my part. Second, I think my problem may stem from my having created this project wrong to begin with. Where I work they like to use EDMX files; I was trying to use a Code First approach, but I think I've got the steps out of sequence or perhaps even left some out. I've tried going back to add EF Code First with Existing Database, but that isn't possible. Guessing I should just start over. Agree?

Comment: Depends. If your database is currently where you need it, start Code First from there (enable-migrations, add-migration Initial -IgnoreChanges, update-database).  Now migrations will only include changes to your model moving forward.

Comment: You can't find the Up() method because you didn't generate the migration yet. The Up() method will be in the MigrationName.cs class generated by this process